# Not able to use executescript selenium method with more than one argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium

I'm trying to automate a site where I can create a list.
The list is created by entering a value in a text field and then setting the value by clicking with the mouse outside the text field.
The previous step is then repeated to enter more elements into the list.
Since we are using Internet Explorer, I'm using Selenium webdriver with IE.
The sendKeys method is very slow, so I would like to use executescript method.

I'm trying to this as follows (it is not working) and I would like to know if anyone has a suggestion.

Code fragment:

```
//Here I declare an arry with the values for the list to be created

String valores[] = {"18","25","60","71"};

//Here I get the WebElement where I'm going to enter the above values one by one

WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='New value:']/parent::div//input[@type='text']"));

JavascriptExecutor myExecutor6 = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver); 

//Now I’m trying to use a for cycle to enter the values one by one, I need to do this, because this is how the UI works    

for(int i=0; i<valores.length; i++){
      System.out.println(valores[i]);
      Thread.sleep(3000);
/*this part is not working, here what I’m trying to do is: I’m trying to write the value of array valores in position ‘i’ in the text field indicated by the WebElement searchField */
/*I have a javascript error, I do notunderstand what is wrong*/

      myExecutor6.executeScript("var valueToWrite = valores[i].toString();"
+"arguments[0].value = valueToWrite ",searchField, valores[i]);

      Thread.sleep(3000);

//This step clicks somewhere else with the mouse to enter the value,
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Values:']")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000);
   }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I've changed the code, it was still failing, then I used the focus() method in javascript and it worked. thanks for trying to help.

for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    iterationNumber = values[i];
    myExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].focus();"+"arguments[0].value = arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='New value:']/parent::div//input[@type='text']")), 
      iterationNumber);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Values:']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='New value:']/parent::div/div/div[2]/button")).click();   
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the code, it was still failing, same problem. It appears that in javascript it is nessary to put the focus on the element. This solved the issue
arguments[0].focus();

thanks for trying to help.

New code:

```
public static void createList(WebDriver driver, String array[]) throws InterruptedException{
```

`String[] values = array.clone();
   String iterationNumber;

   JavascriptExecutor myExecutor = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);

   for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
      System.out.println(values[i]);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      iterationNumber = values[i];
      myExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].focus();"+"arguments[0].value = arguments[1];",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='New value:']/parent::div//input[@type='text']")), 
              iterationNumber);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Values:']")).click();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='New value:']/parent::div/div/div[2]/button")).click();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
   }       
}`